# Is it possible to view the liquidity pool balance of a certain address?

Tags: web3js, bsc, liquidity-provider

For example in PancakeSwap I added a liquidity to ETH/USD having deposited 0.1 ETH and 100 USD. Using Web3, is there a way I can see those deposited tokens if I know the smart contract address of the liquidity pool?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hi there. Do you mean WBNB/BUSD...?

Comment: (https://www.reddit.com/r/pancakeswap/comments/lp5my4/value_of_lp_tokens/)

Comment: Thanks. What I mean is getting how many ETH did I put into the pool.